# converting character pointer to string pointer, removing duplication

Tags: c, string, pointers, atoi

I'm writing a program that takes in a string as input e.g. 35x40x12. I want to then store the numbers as separate elements using an int pointer. So far I've managed to do this so that single digit numbers work, i.e. 3x4x6 works, however if I put in two digit numbers such as 35x40x12, the 35 will be stored in the first position, however in the second position it will also store the 5 from 35, it does this for positions 3 and 4 with regard to 40 as well. How do I remove this duplication?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int present(int l, int w, int h);
int *stringC (char *z);


  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *d = "53x23x4";//input
    printf("%d", *(stringC(d)+2));//whatever's stored in pointer position

    return 0;
}

 int *stringC (char *z)
    {

    int i;
    int *k = malloc(sizeof(int)*20);
    int j = 0;

for(i=0; z[i] !='\0';i++)
   {
     if( z[i]!= 'x')
     {
       k[j]=atoi(&z[i]);
       j++;}
   }


    return k;

}
```

Comment: You want to learn how to sue a debugger, to be able to step through your code and see what is really going on. Also some useful hints here:  http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: After the `atoi` you must advance to the next `'x'` or string terminator, but `i` is still indexing part of the number you have just converted. That's why it works only with single-digit numbers. Better yet, advance to the next non-digit so your algorithm can handle different arithmetic operators.

Comment: C does not have a specific `string` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, **learn to debug**. It's going to be worth it!

---

Have a look at `strtok`. From `man strtok`:

> The `strtok()` function parses a string into a sequence of tokens.

These tokens are divided by delimiters like `"x"`. So, in order to parse the numbers, use something like this:

```
char d[] = "53x23x4";

int array[3];

char* it = strtok(d, "x");

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array) && it; ++i, it = strtok(NULL, "x"))
    array[i] = atoi(it);
```

**Note** that `d` points to an **automatic and writable** string. `strtok` modifies a string's content and since string literal modification yields undefined behavior, you need to allocate the string at a writable location.

Instead of `array` use some dynamic memory allocation mechanism and you have it. This spares you from this inconvenient hassle you're currently using.

---

Notes:

- stop using `char*` to point to string literals. Use `const char*` instead. This prevents subtle errors where you try to modify string literals (undefined behavior).

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how you'd go about using delimiters in C.